# EXTJS--how to pass form values for 2 forms as extraParams?

Tags: extjs

I have two forms whos values I want to pass as extraParams to my grid stores proxy, I just dont know the proper syntax

```
this.getMyGrid().getStore().getProxy().extraParams = this.getForm1().getValues;
```

how would i add this.getForm2().getValues() to the above code?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ext.apply( object, config, [defaults] ), this copies all the properties of config to the specified object. And it's good practice to check the object's properties before use.

```
var me = this,
    formValues = me.getForm1().getValues(),
    store = me.getMyGrid().getStore();

if (formValues && store)
{
    Ext.apply(store.getProxy().extraParams, formValues);
}
```

Comment: While code only answers may answer OP's question, they're hard to understand for other users. Please, provide some explanations to your answer.